# Linearly Independent Set Proof

Tags: formal-proofs

If S = {${v_1,...,v_n}$} is a set of vectors in $R^n$ such that no $v_i$ is a scalar multiple of $v_j$ with $i≠j$, then   {${v_1,...,v_n}$} is linearly independent.

So far, I've used the contrapositive and assumed that the set is dependent and wrote it as a linear combination equalling 0. I'm stuck here.

Comment: what makes you think this claim is even correct?

Comment: Yes, consider $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: As the other two comments pointed out, the statement isn't true.  Do you understand why? Do you understand the counterexample given by @ryagami? If not, please say so.

Comment: I noticed you have asked many questions, but haven't accepted any answers for any of them.  Usually, if you receive a response to one of your questions that you feel answers it, you should click the check mark next to the answer to accept it.  Sometimes if users see that you never accept answers to any of the questions you ask, they may decide not to answer any future questions of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to that particular problem is that it isn't true.However we can find a result in that spirit: if there is no vector in the set that can be expressed as a linear combination of the rest then the set of vectors is independent.

And this in fact can be proved by contrapositive. Mainly what you want to prove is that if a set of vectors is dependent then one vector can be written as a combination of the others.

To prove this note that if the set of vectors is L.D then there is a non-trivial solution to $\alpha_1 v_1+\alpha_2 v_2+\dots\alpha_k v_k =0$ since the solution is non trivial one of the alphas is non-zero, suppose it is $\alpha_k$ . Then

$\alpha_1 v_1+\alpha_2 v_2+\dots\alpha_{k-1} v_{k-1} =-\alpha_k v_{k}$. Since $\alpha_k$ is not zero it has a multiplicative inverse and then $\frac{\alpha_1}{-\alpha_k}v_1+\frac{\alpha_2}{-\alpha_k}v_2+\dots \frac{\alpha_{k-1}}{-\alpha_k}v_{k-1}=v_k$

Comment: Oops yeah, sorry. Thanks for noticing.