# Linearly Independent Set Proof with Cross Product

Tags: formal-proofs

Prove or disprove the statement:

If {v,w} is a linearly independent set of vectors in $R^3$, then {v,w,v cross w} is also linearly independent.

So far, this makes intuitive sense to be true. If u and v are independent, then they lie in the same plane, but not on top of one another. Then v cross w is orthogonal to both, thus it doesn't lie in the plane thus it seems to be true.

I just don't know how to go about writing a formal proof about this.

Comment: Cross product is only defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I think you need to change your question.

Comment: In short, exploit orthogonality of the cross product to the given set of linearly independent vectors. In higher dimensions, you can use the null space of the transpose to select normal vectors, so, while the cross product stops making sense past $n=3$, there are certainly methods to obtain normals... even perpendicularly so...

Comment: Note that this is a special case of the OP's more general question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1100758/11994.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume at the outset $\{ u,v \}$ is a linearly independent set. Let's attack it directly. Consider,
$$ c_1u+c_2v+c_3u\times v =0 $$
we seek to show $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ hence establishing $\{ u,v, u \times v \}$ is a linearly independent set. Take the dot-product with $u$,
$$ c_1u \cdot u +c_2v \cdot u+c_3(u\times v) \cdot u =0 $$
but,$(u\times v) \cdot u = 0$ by the construction of the cross product. Hence,
$$ c_1u \cdot u +c_2v \cdot u =0 $$
Likewise, take dot product with $v$ to uncover:
$$ c_1u \cdot v +c_2v \cdot v =0 $$
We can solve these equations to show $c_1=c_2=0$. Notice $u \cdot u$ and $v \cdot v$ are nonzero as if they were zero it would force $u$ or $v$ to be zero which contradicts the supposed linear independence of $\{u,v \}$. I leave the details to the reader, but, it should be relatively easy algebra.

Next, take dot-product with $u \times v$,
$$ c_1u \cdot (u \times v)+c_2v\cdot (u \times v)+c_3(u\times v)\cdot (u \times v) =0 $$
observe the first two terms are trivial whereas the third returns:
$$ c_3 ||u \times v||^2 = 0.$$
But, $||u \times v|| = ||u||||v|| \sin \theta$ and we already know $\theta \neq 0, \pi$ as $u,v$ cannot be colinear hence $||u \times v||^2 \neq 0$ and we conclude $c_3=0$. There is probably a slicker proof. This is merely the first thing that comes to mind.